# Posting data to SDC HTTP server url from JavaScript shows CORS issue

Tags: cors, streamsets

I am using Streamsets pipeline for streaming data from browsers. So for that, I created a pipeline with HTTP server origin to post data from browsers Javascript and tried to write in that URL using REST client, and it writes successfully.  Response Headers are already set in the SDC.properties file.

```
http.access.control.allow.origin=*
http.access.control.allow.headers=origin, content-type, accept, authorization, x-requested-by, x-ss-user-auth-token, x-ss-rest-call
http.access.control.allow.methods=GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
```

But when I try to write some data from JavaScript using **XMLHTTPRequest**, it throws error for pre-flight request. Below is the JavaScript code:

```
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var value = '{ "prop1": "value 2", "prop2": "value 2" }';
  var url ='http://13.68.93.97:8100/'
  var async = true
 if ('withCredentials' in http) {
    http.open('OPTIONS', url, async);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    http = new XDomainRequest(); //for IE
    http.open('OPTIONS', url);
} else {
    http.open('OPTIONS', url, async);
}
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    http.setRequestHeader('X-SDC-APPLICATION-ID', 'testApp1');
http.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "POST, OPTIONS, GET");
http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true");
http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', "X-Region");
http.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Accept-language");
http.withCredentials = true;
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(value);
```

Error thrown from the above code execution :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://13.68.93.97:8100/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Any help will be really helpful. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Data Collector added CORS support in version 2.4.0.0, released in March 2017

<strike>StreamSets Data Collector doesn't currently support CORS in the [HTTP Server origin](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Origins/HTTPServer.html#concept_s2p_5hb_4y) - those properties in the `sdc.properties` file are for the SDC web UI. I've filed a Jira, [SDC-5298](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-5298), but I'm curious as to your use case. Are you just using the browser for experimentation, or do you see a production use case for users sending data to SDC via JavaScript?</strike>

If you have a production use case, please leave a comment on that Jira and we'll take a look at adding CORS to the HTTP Server origin.

If you just want a way to easily send data, you have a few choices:

1. Use curl from the command line:

   ```
   curl http://localhost:8000/ -H 'X-SDC-APPLICATION-ID: bob' -d '{"a":"b"}'
   ```
2. Install a Chrome extension such as [CORS Toggle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh?hl=en) to disable CORS checking in Chrome.
3. Start Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` option.